# YouTube video cannot be played inline

Tags: video, ios7, youtube-api, xcode5

I'm building an iOS 7 app using Xcode version 5.1.1. I followed a tutorial from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper to create an embedded YouTube video player in my app. According to the tutorial, it should be able to play YT video inline by setting `playsinline` variable to true

```
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
  @"playsinline" : @1,
};
[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"M7lc1UVf-VE" playerVars:playerVars];
```

I've tried it multiple times but the app keep opening the video in Safari instead of playing the video inside the app. Does anyone know how to fix it?